# White lines between divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a basic layout for a website. But I have two problems:

1. I'm getting spaces between my divs. I have already set margin and padding to 0.
2. I can't use % to set hights, I have to use vh for some of the divs and I don't understand why.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4awfk/

HTML:

```
<body>
        <main id="stora">Stora</main>
        <nav id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li id="ettan"><a>Inredningsuppdrag</a></li>
                <li id="tvaan"><a>Instagram</a></li>
                <li id="trean"><a>Kontakt</a></li>
                <li id="fyran"><a>Leverans</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <footer>adress</footer>
    </body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    background: yellow;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
}
#stora {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    float:left;
}
#navigation {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
    float: right;
}
footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    background: white;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}
#ettan {
    width: 50%;
    height: 70vh;
    background: olive;
    float: left;
}
#tvaan {
    width: 50%;
    height: 35vh;
    background: turquoise;
    float: left;
}
#trean {
    width: 50%;
    height: 35vh;
    background: white;
    float: left;
}
#fyran {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30vh;
    background: gray;
    float: left;  
}
```

[image: image of screen]

Comment: What browser are you using? I cannot see any white lines in Chrome

Comment: Actually they are yellow and blue, the background colors of parent elements. I'm using Safari.

Answer (score 3):

To remove the spaces between the divs try setting font-size:0 for the whole document and set a font-size on the anchors or the element containing your text, try this for your example:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size:0;
}
#navigation ul li a {
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Briefly the vh (viewport height) is a new feature in CSS3, I'll explain with an example, if you set your div height to 50vh, this means that you want your div height to stretch to 50% of the viewport height, while setting it to 50% would make stretch to 50% of the div's parent height (same applies for `width:50vw`).

Here is a [**reference**](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) on how to use them.

**EDIT**

Another thing to try:

Try floating only the left div and remove the float from the right div, but set `display:inline-block` for both of them, I can't test the result because I don't have safari, so try it and let us know if it helps.

```
#stora {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
#navigation {
    width:50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I have seen that solution before and I already tried it, but it does not work. Thanks for trying to help and that link to css-tricks was great.

Comment: welcome my friend .. can you post an image from safari to better understand your issue ?

Comment: Sorry, I had to go to work. It worked partially. The yellow line in the middle is completely gone, but the blue line on the right side is still there.

Comment: @Delal my fault, do not remove the width:50% from #navigation, I edited the answer :D

Comment: I didn't do that and the problem remains. Line to the left of both small elements and line under the lower small element. And again, thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Strange, it looks fine in Chrome and Firefox. Darn cross browser compatibility!

You should try:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

I do not have Safari installed to test so this is all I've got, good luck to you sir.

Answer (score -3):

For me:
There was a thin line between dives, so i used

border : 2px solid white;

if you want to set different color for different side of dives, then you should use :-

border-top :
border-right :
border-left :
border-bottom :

based on the side you want to remove the "thin line"
Pardon me if my commenting format is not well defined / sorted (My 1st comment in StackOverFlow)